# Is it possible to populate ListView with List

Tags: android, android-listview, populate

I am new to android and creating a small application where I am getting data from sqlite database and trying to generate a listview from it.

My database helper class method to get data from table:

```
public List<TestClass> getDataFromDb() 
{
    // open database conneciton

    List<TestClass> contactList = new ArrayList<TestClass>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * from mytable";

    Cursor cursor = myDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        do {
            TestClass test = new TestClass();

            test.setName(cursor.getString(0));
            test.setAddress(cursor.getString(1));

            // Adding data to list
            contactList.add(test);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactList;
}
```

and in my onCreate method of **MainActivity.java** class, I am simply calling the above method and getting the List as follow:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DbAdapter info = new DbAdapter(this);

    List<TestClass> nameList = info.getDataFromDb();

    // Get a ListView from main view
    // ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView);

    // set the ListView with "nameList"
}
```

The problem I am having is how to populate ListView after doing **List nameList = info.getDataFromDb();**

Every example that I have seen, is using an ArrayList of type string to create an Adapter and passing that arraylist to the Adapter as 3rd parameter.

Is there a way to generate a ListView by passing it **nameList** ?

Comment: What do you want the ListView to display? Just the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an ArrayAdapter. The simplest approach would be something like:

```
        ArrayAdapter<TestClass> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<TestClass>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList); 
        itcItems.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Note that this simple approach will display the value of TestClass.toString() within the ListView. Override TestClass.toString if you want the text to have a different value.

To change the value of the displayed text include the following method in your TestClass:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getName();
}
```

If you want a custom view (something other than a simple TextView to appear within the ListView) then you will have to extend ArrayAdapter with a custom class.

Comment: @MikeM. I want my ListView to display name and by pressing on the name I want to show the address.

StanSmith I did not understand what you meant by TestClass.toString() within ListView. Now my TestClass simply have two variables and getters / setters methods. One more thing now my app shows the ListView but in following format.
**com.mypackage.db.adapter.TestClass@3939c3ik**
when I press this the address of the person is shown. Why the name of the person is not showing?

Comment: Like Stan Smith says, you need to override (create) the `toString()` method in `TestClass`. An `ArrayAdapter` calls that method on each Object in the list to get the String to display. If you don't override it to show the String you want, e.g. the name, then you get `Object`'s `toString()` method, which returns an Object reference notation, which what you're seeing. So just implement the `toString()` method to return the String `name`.

Comment: @pro_newbie Also, how do you want the address to "show"? A `Toast`? A `Dialog`? Have the list row itself expand to show it?

Comment: @pro_newbie, yes Mike is correct. I added the toString() override to the answer above.